# Draw a border on top of a div

Tags: html, css

OK, I can't explain what I really need so I'll show it.

Or... if I give it a try with words : I need a border, **NOT** around the div, **NOT** changing anything (*width*, *height*, *margins*, *padding* - nothing...), just as if it was drawn **on top of** the aforementioned `div`...

**Example :**

[image]

**CSS :** 
*(targetting the elements with attribute `comp-id` - bordered state is set with the `msp-selected` class)*

```
[comp-id] {
    cursor:pointer;
}

[comp-id] .msp-selected, [comp-id] .msp-selected:hover {
    border:2px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

I've tried with `border`, `outline`, and `box-sizing:border-box;` but none of the above maintains the layout.

So,... Any ideas how this can be achieved?

---

**UPDATE** (Here's what `box-sizing` - yep, ALL of them - does) :

[image]

Let's say we first highlight the upper element (add the border) and then then bottom one - as you may notice, the border *does* affect the layout (like if it adds padding or sth)...

Comment: Have you tried all prefixes on box-sizing, -moz, -webkit?

Comment: Can you show us the CSS code that you're using?

Comment: Can you just put the blue div inside of the red div and set a padding on the red div?  That way, the blue div wouldn't be effected at all.

Comment: Do you have a one coloured background? If so, you could make the div border the same as the background color. ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/VKKQP/))

Comment: `above` or `around`? I just misunderstood.

Comment: You could also use a negative `outline-offset` to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/KGXYR/3/

Answer (score 5):

Box shadow with inset:

```
.box:hover {box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px red;}
```

[see the jsfiddle for further explaination](http://jsfiddle.net/6uRMc/3/)

Comment: The `-webkit` prefix hasn't been needed since Chrome 9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Better safe than sorry, its just 40~ bytes.

Comment: However `W3C` standard property should be the last declaration.

Comment: @Razz Your idea *is* interesting. However I'd really love it if I had to alter nothing - regarding the structure of the already existing HTML code that is...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my pillow forced me to lay upon it for some hours! Check my newest update, think it'll work!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/KGXYR/6/

```
div {
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: thick solid #00ff00;
    outline-offset: -6px
}
```

[outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline)

[outline-offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset)

---

**Update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/XKAVF/

```
.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
}

.box:hover{
     outline: thick solid #00ff00;
     outline-offset: -5px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS border *without* affecting layout margins, paddings, width or height:**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
}

div:hover {
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yWuhU/968/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use box-shadow for that. Example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J88Mk/6/)):

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px red;
```

Will draw a 5px red border at the inner the div - without changing position, height, etc.
Also don't forget to add the various browser prefixes (like `-webkit-`, `-moz`, `-o-`), I just left them for simplicity.

**Edit:**
The advantage compared to `border-box` and `outline` is, you can animate it very well:

`box-shadow`: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J88Mk/8/) vs `border-box`: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yWuhU/960/)

Comment: It wasn't me; to be honest, yours is the answer I'm currently trying (although I've noticed a little quirk in one-or-two cases...)

Answer (score 0):

You found your solution `box-sizing:border-box;`. Just make sure you include -webkit and -moz-box for other browsers, like this:

```
div { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Take in mind that box-sizing is a CSS3 property and won't work in IE7 and IE6.

Here's more on the topic: [How CSS Box Model Works](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Cheers, 
Hope that helps you.

Comment: The `-webkit` prefix hasn't been needed since Chrome 9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `box-sizing` isn't working for you, but perhaps faking it with a pseudo-element will work:

```
div {
    background-color: #6af;
    width: 10em;
    height: 5em;
}
div:hover::before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: thick solid green;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BNqJ/)

This is an interesting article about pseudo-elements: [A Whole Bunch of Amazing Stuff Pseudo Elements Can Do](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/)